# Debugging Quantlib

Tags: quantlib

I am trying to understand Quantlib's finite-difference pricer using Eclipse with GDB debugger.

The code shown below prices an American put option using the Crank-Nicholson finite-difference scheme.

1. I inserted a breakpoint on the line `americanOption.NPV();` and
   attempted to step inside the associated function call, but found
   that the debugger simply steps over to the next line. Why is that?
2. I was eventually able to catch a breakpoint in `void
   TridiagonalOperator::solveFor(const Array& rhs, Array& result)
   const` located in `tridiagonaloperator.cpp`. When I investigate the
   call stack, however, I get an incomprehensible list of function
   calls (screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bid7gae87zzx7tv/Screenshot%202015-12-05%2017.33.48.png?dl=0). How can I interpret this?

Can anyone suggest any strategies to more efficiently debug Quantlib?

```
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>
using namespace QuantLib;

int main()
{
    Calendar calendar = UnitedStates();
    DayCounter dayCounter = Business252();
    Date t(1, Jan, 2014);
    Settings::instance().evaluationDate() = t;
    Date T(31, Dec, 2016);
    Option::Type type(Option::Put);
    Real S0 = 100;
    Real K = 100;
    Real delta = 0.00;
    Real r = 0.01;
    Real sigma = 0.2;

    Handle<Quote> underlying(
            boost::shared_ptr<Quote>(boost::make_shared<SimpleQuote>(S0)));
    Handle<YieldTermStructure> TS(
            boost::shared_ptr<YieldTermStructure>(boost::make_shared<FlatForward>(t, r, dayCounter)));
    Handle<YieldTermStructure> dividendTS(
            boost::shared_ptr<YieldTermStructure>(boost::make_shared<FlatForward>(t, delta, dayCounter)));
    Handle<BlackVolTermStructure> volTS(
            boost::shared_ptr<BlackVolTermStructure>(boost::make_shared<BlackConstantVol>(t, calendar, sigma, dayCounter)));
    boost::shared_ptr<BlackScholesMertonProcess> bsmProcess(
            boost::make_shared<BlackScholesMertonProcess>(underlying, dividendTS,TS, volTS));
    boost::shared_ptr<Exercise> americanExercise(
            boost::make_shared<AmericanExercise>(T));
    boost::shared_ptr<StrikedTypePayoff> payoff(
            boost::make_shared<PlainVanillaPayoff>(type, K));
    VanillaOption americanOption(payoff, americanExercise);
    int timeSteps = 100;
    int gridPoints = 100;
    boost::shared_ptr<PricingEngine> engineFD(
            boost::make_shared<FDAmericanEngine<CrankNicolson>>(bsmProcess, timeSteps,gridPoints));
    americanOption.setPricingEngine(engineFD);
    americanOption.NPV();
    std::cout << "PV = " << americanOption.NPV() << std::endl;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a lot more information, it's difficult to say. Some explanations include (but are not limited to):

- debugging symbols are not present; your system might be missing the `libquant-dbg` (or similar) package. If you compile your own libquant, enable debugging symbols by adding `-g` to your `CFLAGS`.
- Eclipse is not configured correctly; this is a rather large rabbit hole, but if you're absolutely sure that debugging symbols are present, then you might be forced to troubleshoot the IDE. Sometimes an IDE will need to be told explicitly where to find headers and libraries.

Try compiling `quantlib` from source with `CFLAGS=-g` and directly invoke `gdb` on one of the [example executables](https://github.com/lballabio/quantlib/tree/master/QuantLib/Examples).